# How to pass simulation context into Scilab C block?

Tags: c, scilab, xcos

I have been developing my own function block in Scilab/Xcos on the C block basis and I have been struggling with passing parameters defined in the simulation context into the C code. Does anybody know how to do that? Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found functional solution. Let's say I have following parameters defined in the simulation context: `T, RS, RR, LL, LM, pp, K`. In case I place instance of the C block into the simulation and double click on it following window opens

[image]

Then I fill in the parameters which I want to pass into the C block instance (text field Real parameters vector). The parameters values are then accessible in the C language code inside the C block via `block->rpar[0]` (parameter Ts), `block->rpar[1]` (parameter RS), `block->rpar[2]` (parameter RR), `block->rpar[3]` (parameter LL), `block->rpar[4]` (parameter LM), `block->rpar[5]` (parameter pp), `block->rpar[6]` (parameter K)`.